# How to read a two digit numbers in CSV file and storying it in a list?

Tags: python, list, csv

I am scanning a column in Python, which is full of integers. There are some double digit numbers.

```
d = []

for Column in ReadDataSourceFile: #ReadDataSourceFile works well. Its file open and delimiter
    if Column[1] == 'Something' and Column[0] == 'Somewhere':
        countFL += 1
        print Column[5]
        some = map(int, Column[5])
        d.extend(some)

print d
```

Here `Column[5]` is 1, 15, 23, 1, 4, 5. But the print displays [1, 1, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `some = map(int, Column[5])` split number on the digits

```
print map(int, '15')

[1, 5]
```

So print `some` to check it.

Maybe you need only `some = int(Column[5])`

---

**EDIT:** try

```
    print Column[5]
    some = int(Column[5])
    d.append(some)
```

Comment: Yes, map is applying the int() to each of the elements in the string.

Comment: @furas I tried. But it is giving me an error "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Comment: What exactly did you try ? Did you try `print some` ? Did you try `some = int(Column[5])` ?

Comment: Try `some = int(Column[5])` with `d.append(some)` in place of `d.extend(some)`

Comment: BTW: In error message you have number of line which makes problem.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. Without data from `ReadDataSourceFile` it was only guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Your first output looks like a string
Maybe this will work:

```
Column[5].split(',')
```